# AngularJS Json restructure

Tags: angularjs

I can get a json from some services in Angular function, however, there are too many unnecessary things so I am trying to restructure Json to include only data I need.

```
$http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'from some service'}   

        }).success(function(data, status) {

           //this is Json data where I need to remove many things
           $scope.data = data;  

           //this is Json data I need
           $scope.processedJson = [];
      }
```

Let's say $scope.data is

```
{
   "points":[
      {
         "address":"balh",
         "lat":123,
         "long":456
      },
      {
         "address":"balh",
         "lat":321,
         "long":543
      },
      {
         "address":"balh",
         "lat":432,
         "long":333
      }
   ]
}
```

And $scope.processedJson which is ultimately what I need to have is

```
[
   {
      "lat":123,
      "long":456
   },
   {
      "lat":321,
      "long":543
   },
   {
      "lat":432,
      "long":333
   }
]
```

How do I need to run some looping to extract the data I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [forEach](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.forEach)

```
$scope.processedJson = [];
angular.forEach($scope.data.points, function (val) {
    $scope.processedJson.push({
        lat: val.lat,
        long: val.long
    });
});
```

Comment: So simple and easy.. I was stupid thinking about some complex manipulations..  Thanks :)